# Create a 6 page A6 scroll-able PDF document from an A3 InDesign file

Tags: adobe-indesign

I need to to export a file from an A3 InDesign file into a 6 page A6 pdf file that is within a frame that allows user to scroll through the 6 pages and also download the menu, print etc. I have tried to Google how to do so but no luck. I have checked to properties of the file and saw it was done from InDesign. I am relatively new to InDesign so my apology If my terminology is not "up to date" :)

Your help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Just place the source InDesign A3 file into a 6-Page A6 InDesign layout and export that as your PDF.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am a bit of a rookie. How do I do that?

Comment: You can place an InDesign document into another InDesign document as a link via File>Place...

Comment: Thank you. Let me try that and see if I get it right. Will get back to u with results. Much appreciated.